# Geodesic Distance Transform and segmentation operations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, transform, distance, image-segmentation, euclidean-distance

I am interested in using the geodesic distance transform in Matlab (2015a) to obtain segmented regions of a picture, from which I can perform operations on a particular region.

I have incorporated the code outlined from here (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imseggeodesic.html) and can reproduce their images. However, I'm not sure how to perform operations on any particular segmented area.

L = imseggeodesic(RGB,BW1,BW2);
figure, imshow(label2rgb(L));

The above snippet would display the picture segmented into light and dark blue regions, of which the dark blue region represents the yellow flower from the original picture. How may I proceed to, for example, perform colour histogram equalisation for the yellow flower alone?

Displaying L alone (without label2rgb) results in a plain white image leading me to assume it's blank (as in has no value for me to work with). So can I store label2rgb(L) into another variable, threshold the light blue region (which is the background, not the flower) and perform operations to influence the yellow flower alone? Or would it be better to use:

[L,P] = imseggeodesic(RGB,BW1,BW2)

for threshold purposes?

Any sort of advice, especially coding would be of great assistance.

Answer (score 0):

- L is from type double, it is a matrix with values 1 and 2. The pixels assigned a 1 are classified as flower (because of the first sample area: BW1), those assigned 2 are classified as background (because of the second sample area: BW2).
- If you want to transform the L matrix into a binary image use the following code:

  `[r,c]=size(L);% row and column length matrix L
      BW=[];
      for i=1 : r ;
          for j=1:c;
              if L(i,j)==2;
                  BW(i,j)=1;% assign class 2 a 1 (true)
              else BW(i,j)=0;% assign class 1 a 0 (false)
              end
          end
      end`

You can see the result as follows :

`figure;imshow(BW);% background is assigned a 1 (1= true= white) and the flower 0 (0=false=black)`

The inverse of the image is done as follows:
`BWinverse=~BW;
figure;imshow(BWinverse); % background is assigned a 0 and the flower 1`

- If you want to segment the background further use :

  `maskedRgbImage = bsxfun(@times,RGB, cast(BW, class(RGB)));
  figure;imshow(maskedRgbImage);%puts a mask on the flower (assigns the background pixels a 0)`
- If you want to segment the flower further use :

  `maskedRgbImage = bsxfun(@times,RGB, cast(BWinverse, class(RGB)));
  figure;imshow(maskedRgbImage);% puts a mask on the background`